# Copy document between libraries

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, rest, jquery, versioning

In **library1** that has major versions activated, **document A** has 30 versions and same document is copied, programmatically, in **library2** there are 10 versions.

User realizes he made a mistake and wants to roll back version of document in library 1, to version 10 from library2.
What I know is that I can do it but to loose versions in library1, what I want is to roll back to desired version but to keep versions.

So new version of document1 in library1 will be version 31 and it will be a copy of 10th version from document1 from library2.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

when you revert back to a version you actually promote the older version to be the new version

so:

if you have version 31 and you revert to version 10 
what you'll have is version 32 (which is version 10)

if you want to have copies of version then you'll have to copy your current version, Save the copy, Restore save the copy again, and restore again

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I know how versioning works. I was asking if it is possible programatically/SPD to copy version of document from library2 to library1, but to keep previous versions alive.

Comment: just push the document version, you'll have both version, sharepoint does not override versions even when you restore them. but the version number and date will change

Comment: with what command? copy does erase previous versions and update don't update document itself but only metadata columns